# How to write the probability distribution function for this?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A point Y is first selected from the interval (0,1)
Then a point X is selected from the interval (Y,1)
What is the probability distribution function of X?

I thought it should be f(x) = 1/(1-Y), but it seems wrong because then if Y=1, f(x)=undefined, while it should actually be zero...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$  is uniform on the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$.

The joint density is $2$ in that triangle, and $0$ elsewhere. To find the density function of $X$, "integrate out" $y$. For $0\lt x\lt 1$, we get $f_X(x)=2x$.

Comment: Thanks! Got it.. But still.. Why was I wrong?

Comment: You are  welcome. I made a comment earlier about one structural thing that was wrong about your suggestion.

Comment: But... Why was I wrong?

Comment: The *conditional density* of $X$ given $Y=y$ is  $\frac{1}{1-y}$ over a suitable interval. But conditional density given $Y=y$ is not the same thing as density.

Comment: Ohh... I think I get it now.. Thanks a lot!!